# Testing a ViewModel in WPF MVVM with Moq framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, repository, moq

I am new to Moq framework. I have a viewmodel with injected `IEntityRepository`

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly IEntityRepository _entityRepository;

    public MainViewModel(IEntityRepository entityRepository)
    {
        _entityRepository = entityRepository;
        Entities = new ObservableCollection<EntityWrapper>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EntityWrapper> Entities { get; set; }

    public void Load()
    {
        var entities = _entityRepository.GetAll();

        Entities.Clear();

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            Entities.Add(new EntityWrapper(entity));
        }
    }

    public void AddEntity(string name, int x, int y)
    {
        var entity = new Entity()
        {
            Name = name,
            X = x,
            Y = y
        };
        _entityRepository.AddEntity(entity);
        _entityRepository.Save();
    }
}
```

and `EntityRepository` is like this:

```
public class EntityRepository : IEntityRepository
{
    private Context _context;

    public EntityRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Entity Get(long id)
    {
        return _context.Entities.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Entity> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Entities.ToList();
    }

    public void AddEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        _context.Entities.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test `Load` and `AddEntity` methods of `MainViewModel` 
this is my test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class MainViewModelTests
{
    private Mock<IEntityRepository> _mockRepo;
    private MainViewModel _mainViewModel;

    public MainViewModelTests()
    {
        _mockRepo = new Mock<IEntityRepository>();
        _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(_mockRepo.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddEntityTest()
    {
        var entity = new Entity()
        {
            Name = "Student",
            X = 10,
            Y = 20
        };

        _mainViewModel.AddEntity("Student", 10, 20);

        _mockRepo.Setup(m => m.AddEntity(entity));
        _mockRepo.Setup(m => m.Save());

        var entities = _mainViewModel.Entities;
        Assert.AreEqual(1, entities.Count);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void LoadTest()
    {
        // How to add fake data???

        _mockRepo.Setup(r => r.GetAll());

        _mainViewModel.Load();

        var entities = _mainViewModel.Entities;
        Assert.AreEqual(1, entities.Count);
    }
}
```

In `AddEntityTest()` I don't know why the property `Entities` will be empty and in `LoadTest` how to populate fake data so that I can load it.

Comment: you can use [AutoMoq](https://github.com/darrencauthon/AutoMoq) or create it yourself with [Mock.Of<>](https://cmatskas.com/improve-your-unit-tests-with-mock-of/)

Comment: You can use [`returns`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods) for that

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski for what? the output of both `AddEntity` and `Save` methods are void so I cannot use `Returns`

Comment: @styx you mean for generating fake data?

Comment: @PaleBlossom yes

Answer (score 1):

To get a test data in `LoadTest` method you can use `Moq` [`Returns`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods) method

```cs
_mockRepo.Setup(r => r.GetAll()).Returns(new List<Entity> { new Entity() });
```

It works, because [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

As for the `AddEntityTest`, there are a couple of issues here. You setup the mock

```cs
_mockRepo.Setup(m => m.AddEntity(entity));
_mockRepo.Setup(m => m.Save());
```

after `_mainViewModel.AddEntity("Student", 10, 20);` call. It should come before, *Arrange* step is always before *Act* step, according to [`AAA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2019#write-your-tests) pattern

You also don't update `Entities` collection after adding an entity, so the `Entities.Count` remains the same. I suggest you to setup a `IEntityRepository.GetAll()` mock as well for this test and update an `Entities` collection in `MainViewModel`. Or rewrite the logic of your `AddEntityTest`, if collection update performed through view

Comment: @PaleBlossom Does it answer your question, do you need more information or details here?